# AODV implementation for Kernel 3.8 or above

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, adhoc

I am working on a research project where I will be creating a proactive protocol similar to AODV. Creating the protocol from the scratch will be a tedious and time consuming task and it will be time saving If I implement the protocol from already working AODV.

I can find AODV for old linux kernel such as 2.6.x such as famous AODV-uu from http://sourceforge.net/projects/aodvuu/. They are not compiling properly against the newer version for kernel version 3.8 and above. Does anyone have know AODV for latest kernel or does anyone AODV-uu for latest kernel version. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to port that driver to a recent kernel (which probably is less effort than rewriting it from scratch)? Or ask the original author?

Comment: What is your kernel -v? which version of ns are you using now?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for replying. May I know what do you mean by port that driver to recent kernel???

Comment: @Naveen.S thanks for replying. my kernel version is 3.8.0.....

Comment: I mean take and study the source code from sourceforge, become familiar with latest 3.11 kernel internals, and update the source code till it works well with that kernel. Don't forget to interact with the Linux kernel community, and to contribute your improvements.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for your suggestion. I tried something similar, by compiling and trying to remove the errors by looking into similar error online, but I have to make too many changes and I gave up on that idea. Probably I will learn more on kernel network internal and try to modify it again. I am also trying to develop it from scratch. Lets see which which will be easier. Once I am done I will share it with open source community..

Comment: Do you want implement protocol like AODV in simulator (ns2) am i right?

Comment: Please share it while working on it, and try to get valuable feedback. Don't start interacting with the open source community when you are done, but start right now, before coding the first line....

Comment: @Naveen.S no i am not working in simulator... I am looking on more real-time implementation......

Answer (score 0):

AODV -UU is the only source. Are you going to implement your protocol in real time or in stimulation?
There is no development in Aodv kernel version. If u wish make use of aodv existing code and compile it for newer kernel version.